# Missing AddressBook.framework in iOS Project

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-mavericks, ios-frameworks

I'm developing for iOS and try to link AddressBook.framework in my iOS project. All other frameworks are available and get linked without any problems. I'm using Xcode 6.1 and my development target is iOS 7.0 on OS X Mavericks.

I have tried to create a new empty project, but it is not listed in the popup for adding frameworks.

Does anyone have expierience how to enable / install that missing framework? Or is this a Xcode bug?

Thanks in Advance!

[image: Frameworks]

Comment: check `Project Targets -> Build Settings -> Search Paths`, can you tell me what values are set with `Framework Search Paths`

Comment: the value is: `$(PROJECT_DIR)/<MyAppName>/Libs` `non-recursive`

Comment: add `$(inherited)` (non-recursive), clean project and build. Let me know the result.

Comment: thanks but the linker error is still there: `ld: framework not found AddressBook`

Comment: have you cleaned the project and then build?

Comment: yep many times... all other frameworks are linked, so i think just this one is missing somehow

Comment: do you have the `AddressBook.framework` present in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`

Comment: no just `AddressBookUI.framework` but not `AddressBook.framework`. can u tell me how to add the missing framework? if you post a working answer i will accept it :)

Comment: I have uploaded the framework (zipped) here: https://www.mediafire.com/?ebrhx13pqwysw3c . Unzip & place it in the aforementioned location and restart XCode. Let me know the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `AddressBook.framework` (uploaded here in zipped format: https://www.mediafire.com/?ebrhx13pqwysw3c ) to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Develope‌​r/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks` and restart XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Guys who are facing **AddressBook.framework** or **AddressBookUI deprecation** bug in **iOS 9**, **Use Contact.framework and ContactsUI.framework**.

Comment: So how would that be used, can you show how code using one would be written using the other?